# Android: Post JSON data with HttpURLConnection to the localhost(WAMP)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am trying to post JSON string with the HttpURLConnection to the localhost server(WAMP). In my approach I am invoking the AsyncTask class from the timer but I am facing the problem when the compiler reaches this line `handler.post(new Runnable()` it jumps back to `while (run)` and not enter the `public void run() {new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);}`

The JSON String which I am getting from convertToJSON method:

```
{ 
    "formatted" : "22.04.2015 11:11:00",
    "latitude" : 53.869073210000003,
    "longitude" : 10.66542435,
    "route" : 4
}
```

This part of code is in the onLocationChanged method in the inner class "MyLocationListener" of the MainActivity:

```
String jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted);
PostData sender = new PostData(jSONString);
sender.timer();
```

PostData class:

```
package com.bustracker;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;

public class PostData {
    String jSONString;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public PostData(String jSONString) {
        super();
        this.jSONString = jSONString;
    }

    public String getjSONString() {
        return jSONString;
    }

    public void setjSONString(String jSONString) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;
    }

    public void timer() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean run = true;
                while (run) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);// 60000 milliseconds which is 60
                                            // seconds

                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // here you send data to server
                                new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        run = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                //This is the ip address of my laptop wifi because I am running the app in my device and I want to send the data to the localhost server(WAMP). 
                URL myUrl = new URL("http://192.168.X.X/webservice"); 
                HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                        .openConnection();
                myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                myConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                myConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                myConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                myConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/json");
                myConnection.connect();
                // create data output stream
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                        myConnection.getOutputStream());
                // write to the output stream from the string
                wr.writeBytes(jSONString);
                wr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Quick question, why the handler? Couldn't you directly execute the asynctask after the sleep statement ?

Comment: new Handler and new MyAsyncTask need to be instantiated within main thread on the android app. try to execute new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString); from a button click and insert the Thread.sleep to the beginning of the doInBackground method...

Comment: @Markus: I dont need the button but does that mean I have to put the thread in the doInBackground method?

Comment: As I understood it, the onPostExecute is running on main thread. That's why any Async Task needs to know "its" main thread. The doInBackground is running an extra background thread by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are already using Handler, you can use it as a timer.

```
public void timer() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean run = true;
            while (run) {
               handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);
                   }
               }, 5000);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

for reference, visit http://binarybuffer.com/2012/07/executing-scheduled-periodic-tasks-in-android

Comment: I tried your code but it is always sticking here `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {`